# Non-integer indexed Indexer properties in C#

Tags: c#, properties, indexed-properties

I want to have an indexed property in C#:

```
public Boolean IsSelected[Guid personGuid]
{
   get {
      Person person = GetPersonByGuid(personGuid);
      return person.IsSelected;
   }
   set {
      Person person = GetPersonByGuid(personGuid);
      person.IsSelected = value;
   }
}
public Boolean IsApproved[Guid personGuid]
{
   get {
      Person person = GetPersonByGuid(personGuid);
      return person.IsApproved;
   }
   set {
      Person person = GetPersonByGuid(personGuid);
      person.IsApproved= value;
   }
}
```

Visual Studio complains on the non-integer indexer syntax:

i know [.NET supports non-Integer indexors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1a8yx17k.aspx).

---

In another language i would write:

```
private
   function GetIsSelected(ApproverGUID: TGUID): Boolean;
   procedure SetIsSelected(ApproverGUID: TGUID; Value: Boolean);
   function GetIsApproved(ApproverGUID: TGUID): Boolean;
   procedure SetIsApproved(ApproverGUID: TGUID; Value: Boolean);
public
   property IsSelected[ApproverGuid: TGUID]:Boolean read GetIsSelected write SetIsSelected;
   property IsApproved[ApproverGuid: TGUID]:Boolean read GetIsApproved write SetIsApproved;
end;
```

Comment: `C# does not limit the index type to integer.` - From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02.aspx). Not sure why it complains.

Comment: What is the actual error you're receiving?

Comment: You missed the this keyword before []

Comment: @MohsenAfshin i didn't miss the `this`, i just called it `IsSelected`. If it were called `this`, then it would mean there's only one indexed property.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect:

```
public Boolean this[Guid personGuid]
{
   get {
      Person person = GetPersonByGuid(personGuid);
      return person.IsSelected;
   }
   set {
      Person person = GetPersonByGuid(personGuid);
      person.IsSelected = value;
   }
}
```

Indexers are declared using the `this` keyword - you can't use your own name.

From [Using Indexers (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02.aspx):

> To declare an indexer on a class or struct, use the this keyword

---

Additionally, it is only possible to have one indexer that accepts a type - this is a limitation of the indexer syntax of C# (might be an IL limitation, not sure).

Comment: That would mean that i can't have two (e.g. `IsSelected[Guid personGuid]` and `IsApproved[Guid personGuid]`) indexed properties?

Comment: @IanBoyd - True. One limitation of indexers. Though you could have an `IsApproved[string reallyAGUID]` and parse into a GUID (ugly hack, but you see where I am going).

Comment: @IanBoyd: Correct. You can have multiple indexors if they have different types of keys, but you can't have indexes work how you want them to. You'd be better off with a `ToggleSelected(Guid personGuid)` and an `ToggleApproval(Guid personGuid)` methods, or something similar.

Comment: Update your answer with *"cannot do - limitation of indexers"* and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 5):

Indexers only work with the `this` keyword. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx).

> The this keyword is used to define the indexers.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: I've been proven wrong enough times to be careful about making absolute statements.

Comment: i think that the compiler has a way of shutting that whole thing down.

Answer (score 1):

Just like Matt Burland and Oded said, indexers only work with this keyword, so you need to have a proxy class with the interface you need:

```
public class PersonSelector
{
    private MyClass owner;

    public PersonSelector(MyClass owner)
    {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public bool this[Guid personGuid]
    {
       get {
          Person person = owner.GetPersonByGuid(personGuid);
          return person.IsSelected;
       }
       set {
          Person person = owner.GetPersonByGuid(personGuid);
          person.IsSelected = value;
       }
    }

}

public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        this.IsSelected = new PersonSelector(this);
    }   

    public PersonSelector IsSelected { get; private set; }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jojan answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431339/c-sharp-multiple-indexers):

> C# 3.0 spec
>
> "Overloading of indexers permits a class, struct, or interface to
>   declare multiple indexers, provided their signatures are **unique** within
>   that class, struct, or interface."

or if your data set is small you can IList

```
public IList<Boolean> IsSelected
{
   get { ... }
}

public IList<Boolean> IsApproved
{
   get { .... }
}
```

or use [Multiple Indexers technique using Interfaces](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12732/Multiple-Indexers-In-a-Class-Using-Interface-Index)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can have multiple indexers accepting types.

However you can not have two indexers with the same signature. Same signature means the parameter number and types - so the above code has two indexers with same signature.

If the code changed to :

```
    Boolean this[string x, Guid personguid]
```

and :

```
    Boolean this[Guid personguid]
```

it should work.