# Indexer Property

Tags: c#, indexer

When we use the indexer property, we don't give it any parameter that will make this indexer property refer to the array that we want. What if we have more than one array?

How do we specify or force this property to refer to a specific array if we have more than one array in the class?

Comment: Why is this tagged `facebook`? Please tag appropriately.

Comment: Why not simply reading the [MSDN entry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02.aspx) on that topic?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding of an indexer may be slightly off. An indexer essentially doesn't have any relation to some underlying array. It merely provides a way to define a syntax similar to those used to access array elements.

In fact, the built-in `Dictionary` class uses it with non-integer arguments to provide access to dictionary values via their corresponding key objects.

Also, indexers can take more than one parameter. You could, for example, define an enumeration of values representing the various arrays your class contains and return or set the appropriate value of the corresponding array, then.

Comment: you are right, i should learn more about the indexers , thanks your answer was helpful

Answer (score 0):

You have to use properties that take arguments, 
Which is not possible in C#, unfortunately

```
public string this[int index] 
{ 
    get { return namelist[index]; } 
    set { namelist[index] = value; } 
}
```

The indexer points to the array variable you use inside the indexer.

Comment: so what will happen if we used an indexer property with a class that contains more than one array ,Which array it would refer to?

Comment: @WafaAl-mardiney http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431339/c-sharp-multiple-indexers